# Does every undirected graph contain a cycle?

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose there is a **DIRECTED** Graph which contains 2 nodes A and B. There is and edge connecting A to B. Now this directed graph does not contain a cycle. But as soon as I add an edge from B to A a cycle exists now. Now in the case of **UNDIRECTED** Graph which contains 2 nodes A and B. Here Both nodes can be accessed from each other. Like you can go to A from B and to B from A. So is this not a cycle ?

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/ - this is a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you define a cycle in an undirected graph.

The problem is that you have to use the same edge twice in order to complete the cycle in the **undirected** graph. While in the **directed** graph you use different edges to get from A to B and from B to A